# Identify GSM encryption algorithm

Tags: android, encryption, gsm

I would like to find out whether my android phone (ADP) is using A5/0, A5/1 or A5/2 at a specific time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm curious about that too..

Got some answers?

Al

Answer (score 7):

The encryption algorithms for GSM are done in the GSM modem and not in the Android OS. The encryption algorithm that your phone uses depends on your carrier and the GSM modem. You probably won't be able to find out what algorithm it is using at a given time since Andorid is only communicating with the GSM modem using AT-commands that often obfuscate those details.

[Here is a paper on GSM architecture.](http://gnumonks.org/~laforge/papers/gsm_phone-anatomy-latest.pdf)